# Expo Video Player is throwing Required value was null Error

Tags: react-native, expo

I try to show a video in my react native expo app, but either with video and video player i get the same error "Required value was null" invoked by the ViewDefinitionBuilder.

Even if i did a copy paste from this:

```
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/video/
https://github.com/ihmpavel/expo-video-player
```

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { VideoPlayer } from 'expo-video-player';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <VideoPlayer
        videoProps={{
          shouldPlay: true,
          resizeMode: Video.RESIZE_MODE_CONTAIN,
          source: {
            uri: 'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4',
          },
        }}
        inFullscreen={true}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

Also this is not working, neither with a video from the internet streamed or local:

```js
          <View style={styles.container}>
          <Video
            ref={video}
            style={styles.video}
            source={{
              uri: require('./big_buck_bunny_short.mp4'),
            }}
            useNativeControls
            resizeMode="contain"
            isLooping
            onPlaybackStatusUpdate={setStatus}
          />
          <View style={styles.buttons}>
            <Button
              title={status.isPlaying ? 'Pause' : 'Play'}
              onPress={() =>
                status.isPlaying ? video.current.pauseAsync() : video.current.playAsync()
              }
            />
          </View>
        </View>
```

Do i need an addional permission?
My Audio Player works like fine.

Comment: Did you try to use `expo-av` instead of `expo-video-player` ?

Comment: yes. Same error

Comment: Is Proguard enabled for your project?. Try to upgrade to this release version or above - https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/main/packages/expo-av/CHANGELOG.md#1310--2022-12-30